# How to distribute a Polymer Web Component?

Tags: web, build, polymer, web-component, polymer-3.x

I'm trying to develop a first Web Component using the Polymer Framework: https://polymer-library.polymer-project.org/3.0/docs/devguide/feature-overview

At the end, I want to produce a Web Component which will be distributed into several Web Application.

It's not clear yet for me how I can package such a Component.

Of course I can provide a copy of all the required Javascript files and ask people to put them at the right place, etc ... But at best, I would like to compact everything in a single JS file, so that the final user of my component just had to include one script, and need to deal with one single JS file.

Is there a way to build such file? Or what is the philosophy when distributing such components?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not really sure what you mean by distributing. Most components are currently published on https://www.npmjs.com/. `npm publish` basically creates a zip file and makes it easily installable for everyone.

Comment: That's the thing, I don't want to publish on npm Repository. We only want to distribute it locally, but without having to deliver "tons of" Javascript files, or without having to extract lots of folders ... Is there a way to put all what's required in a single Javasctip file ?

Comment: what you are describing is sort of a "compiled/bundled" version of your component... you can use rollup/webpack/pikapkg/... for it - with that, you can output a single file that contains all the needed code - Note however if you have multiple components that share a dependency (which is most likely) that those dependnecies will be shipped multiple times... which incrises your download and needed parse time...

Comment: Thanks daKomoR, exactly what I was looking for! i'll give a try with one of these tools.